# I need help cleaning up my code, and with my jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with my code because my jQuery for my signup navbar and search icon isn't working correctly. Also for some reason, my icon bars for mobile devices with bootstrap isn't responding on click.

My code is below.

```
  <a href="http://jsbin.com/voxamevoze/edit?html,output">
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, I recommend reading [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [complete, minimal, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please don't link to 3rd party sites when you can include your code on SO. We shouldn't have to go somewhere else just to see your issue. Also, please don't link to an entire project for us to hunt around to find your issue or the code in question - just include the relevant parts needed to replicate the issue you're running into.

Comment: you def. need to close the a tag with '</a>'

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is a mess. At least split out the code into the different sections so it'll be easier for us to help debug it for you.

Anyways this is the main problem with your code:

```
jQuery('html').click(function (event) {
    jQuery('.dropdown-menu1').fadeOut( "first" );
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

You are assigning a click handler on the entire html document and preventing any bubbling from occurring. You should only assign the click event to the element that is being interacted with, like:

```
$('#dropdown-toggle1').click(function(event){
    jQuery('.dropdown-menu1').fadeOut( "first" );
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also, the target element for your navbar toggle button is wrong, so it doesn't trigger the bootstrap navbar js:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
```

`data-target` should refer to your target nav element, which in this case is `data-target="#navbar"`

Finally, the menu icon does not display in your sample code because you didn't link a working copy of the fontawesome library in the sample. The css source listed points to your local version.